# PC double boots before POST, then boots normally

Tags: boot, bios, troubleshooting, post, cmos

When turned on from any power state (S1-S5), including sleep modes, my PC turns on, then off, then back on and boots as if from shutdown, thus losing work and closing programs. The shutdown occurs before the screen turns on and before BIOS are even loaded (also from sleep mode where OS is still loaded). The whole process takes ~5 seconds. All temps are normal. No Overclocking. Was left in padded box for 3 months (not in sun) before starting this.

**What I've tried:**

- GPU removed
- all fans removed
- all disks and drives removed
- PSU (tested with alternate PSU)
- RAM alternated (unless both are going. both still work when the PC boots)
- network card removed
- all peripherals removed
- CMOS battery replaced
- BIOS updated (1.4 to 1.11)
- CMOS cleared via jumper
- Boot order checked (it's correct)
- ordered stray cables (none touch any metal other than case)

Literally everything except for MOBO and CPU have been tested or removed and the problem persists while booting. Everything still works perfectly once powered on.

I'm worried this is putting wear on other components and that it's symptomatic of something larger. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Specs:**

- CPU: Intel i5-4670K 3.4gHz
- GPU: Sapphire Radeon HD 7950 3gB
- RAM: Corsair Vengeance DDR3-1600 2x4gB
- MOBO: MSI Z87-G43 ATX LGA1150 (BIOS 1.11, previously 1.4)
- PSU: Corsair CX600M ATX